# Media uploader "uploading" multiple instances of the same image

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ftp, image-uploading

When I select some images and drop into the wordpress file uploader, the first image of the group seems to upload correctly at this moment, while the others freeze and aren't being processed.

However, after some time waiting, I've stopped the process, reloaded the browser tab, and at "Media" section, multiple instances of the same image, all of them with their respective ID by the way, are there, and are more instances than the number of images previously selected.

Looking on FTP, on the upload folder, there are a large number of the same image that differ in a suffix that seems to be a counter of the number of files.

Other odd thing that happens is that, even after logging out, some instances of the same file appears and the number keep growing.

I have installed the following plugins and everything is fine, except for this odd behavior:

- Contact Form 7
- Custom Content Type Manager : Advanced Custom Post Types
- WooCommerce
- Maintenance
- Really Simple CAPTCHA
- WooCommerce Correios
- WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields for Brazil
- WooCommerce PagSeguro

Comment: try to restart server ... it looks like the script gone in an infinite loop or something :) and set max execution time to 60sec ;)

Comment: While you upload *multiple* images keep an eye on the browser tools network tab, it might give some clue as to what your browser is doing.

Comment: @Bob0t, I need to contact my host because isn't possible to control the instance of Apache remotely. About the upload monitoring, Loz Cherone, there's no way to do it now, the server is running out memory and keeps creating images... I'll have to wait for now...

However, to avoid this problem futurely, what do you recommend to do, while Wordpress community states that the version is stable (3.9.1-pt-br)? It seems that is an issue on the CMS, don't you think?

Comment: it's write, but if there is an issue, i think it's mostly cuz your host authorize infinite no ending long long scripts ... :p open a ticket and ask max_execution_time 60sec ;) at least your server will not be full of the same image :D

Comment: Follow this guide: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-39-master-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time looking for a solution, @brasofilo suggested me to follow a guide because the current version of Wordpress (3.9) was release with some bugs and misconceptions.

My problem was with image editor that, on my host, isn't working correctly. At this thread on Wordpress Support (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/http-error-on-media-upload-wp-39?replies=16), one guy suggested this little filter snippet which returns the image editor to back to default:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Default to GD
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-to-gd
Description: Sets GD as default WP_Image_Editor class.
Author: Mike Schroder
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.getsource.net/
*/

function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';

    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );

    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
?>
```

And then, my problem was solved.